# Como fazer com que carregue a url completa do welcome-file

Tags: jsf-2.2, java-ee, servlet

No web.xml esta mapeado assim:

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>agendamento/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Ao abrir a aplicação no browser esta abrindo certo, mas preciso que essa url esteja presente por causa de um redirect nesse index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A configuração `welcome-file` não serve para fazer redirecionamentos.

A ideia é: quando um usuário acessa um diretório não mapeado da sua aplicação, o web container irá procurar naquele diretório por arquivos com os respectivos nomes.

Para redirecionar o usuário a partir da raiz da aplicação, crie um filtro ou servlet mapeando mapeado na raiz (`/`) que faça esse redirecionamento via código.

Ou, mova o arquivo `index.html` para a raiz da sua aplicação e mude a configuração para:

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Finalmente, faça o redirecionamento a partir daí.

Por outro lado, se você quer redirecionar o usuário que acessar `/agendamento/`, simplesmente deixe o arquivo `index.html` na pasta agendamento e use a configuração acima, sem especificar o diretório.

Comment: Muito bem explicado, valeu cara.